# Close Anki gracefully from script

Tags: anki

I'd like to be able to close Anki (Linux) gracefully via script so that all recent changes are properly committed to the database.

If I just use kill command all uncommitted changes aren't saved. Is there some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to figure out that this command does a graceful exit:

```
kill -s SIGINT `pidof anki`
```